# SQLAlchemy insert new records with many to one relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, relationship

I am not sure if this is even possible but here goes, example code:

Two example classes which I believe represent a many to one relationship:

```
class Book(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'book'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100))
    status_id = Column(ForeignKey(u'status.id'))
    status = relationship(u'Status', back_populates="books")

class Status(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'status'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    books = relationship("Book", back_populates="status")
```

In the status table I have records like so:

```
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | draft        |
|  2 | in progress  |
|  3 | under review |
|  4 | finished     |
+----+--------------+
```

Here is the question, is there any way to create a Book like this:

```
book = Book()
book.name = "Relationships in SQL"
book.status.name = "finished"
```

When creating a brand new Book record, the "status" property is None so this isn't possible. I tried to be sneaky and did this:

```
book = Book()
book.name = "Relationships in SQL"
book.status = Status(name="finished")
```

but as I expected this created a brand new entry in the status table.

What I am trying to achieve is to create a Book without having to look up the correct id from "status" first.

If this isn't possible I can live with it but I would just like to know either way. I can't seem to find any docs which relate to this situation.

Comment: How would the system know the ID of the correct status in the DB without looking it up?

Comment: I would imagine if this scenario were possible it would do the lookup behind the scenes. I am trying to create records without explicitly writing code to do the lookup first. SQLAlchemy can do a lot of clever things with relationship properties and I wanted to know if something like this would be possible.

Comment: One of the answers on the duplicate is from the creator of SQLAlchemy.